# Haskell - swap words in a function

Tags: string, haskell, swap

I'm trying to create a function which swaps a string (w1) in a sentence with another string (w2). Here is what I have so far:

```
swapwords :: String -> String -> String -> String 
swapwords w1 w2 [] = [] 
swapwords w1 w2 (x:xs) 
    | length (x:xs) < n = (x:xs) 
    | otherwise = do 
if w1 == take n (x:xs) then w2 ++ swapwords w1 w2 (drop n (x:xs)) 
else x:swapwords w1 w2 xs 
where 
    n = length w1
```

However, I'm getting an 'undefined variable "main"' error, and 'Warning: Defined but not used: `w1'' and 'w2'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like an indentation problem; remember that Haskell is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: You also shouldn't use the do in this context. That's reserved for when you want to work with monads (and while lists form a monad, you aren't using the list monad here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to you trying to build an executable from a module that does not define a function `main`. The warnings are caused by your code being somewhat awkwardly indented (I am assuming that you are using a Haskell 98 compiler; GHC 7.8.3 accepts your code if you compile it in Haskell 2010 mode.)

Although you can use `do`-notation to construct expressions of type `String` (as strings are lists and the type constructor for lists is a monad), it is a bit strange to do it in this context (you are not really doing anything monadic with the string you are constructing, aren't you?).

Slightly reformatting your code and adding a function `main` will make your code compile (also as Haskell 98) to an executable:

```
swapwords :: String -> String -> String   -> String 
swapwords    w1        w2        []       =  [] 
swapwords    w1        w2        (x : xs)
  | length (x:xs) < n                     = x : xs  
  | otherwise                             =
      if   w1 == take n (x:xs)
      then w2 ++ swapwords w1 w2 (drop n (x:xs)) 
      else x : swapwords w1 w2 xs 
  where 
    n = length w1

main :: IO ()
main =  putStrLn (swapwords "bar" "qux" "foo bar baz")
```

Running this executable then allows you to test your code:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3

$ ghc -XHaskell98 Test.hs -o test.exe
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking test.exe ...

$ ./test.exe 
foo qux baz
```

Answer (score 0):

While this has nothing to do with your compile problems, here is another way you could implement your function using `Text.Regex.PCRE`:

```
module Swap where

import Text.Regex.PCRE ((=~))

swap :: String -> String -> String -> String
swap orig toSwap ws =
  case ws =~ orig :: (String,String,String) of
   (_,"","") -> ws
   (b,_,a) -> b ++ toSwap ++ a
```

Although [this text-icu library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu) is probably better for this by now, as `Text.Regex` doesn't support `Text.Data.Text`